# Use Deep learning or RL to maximize long term hit in caching file?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, reproducible-research

Suppose I have **F** video files with **different file size** and with **different popularity**.

I have a memory cache of fixed size. What I have to do is following:

**I want to cache n files (n < F) in memory of local device such that the long term average hit maximizes. In other words which files should I cache in local cache memory such that probability of watching that video file maximizes.** Note:- *total memory cache is of fixed size.*

For this problem I have to learn some function which can predict the user's interest so that model can cache right files. But which machine learning technique should I use? Should I go with Deep Learning or Reinforcement Learning? Please suggest any useful research paper or study materials.

*Please note I have to use the user's browsing history to find his/her interest.*

Comment: Forget buzz words like Deep Learning and Reinforcement Learning for a moment and focus on what you want to solve. Make a simple relevant solution and then built up from that. A base-line solution is paramount so you know if you throw time and money down the drain or you actually get tangible improvements.

Comment: Sir, I thought a lot but not able to find any simple solution. In order to learn user interest I need to use RL? If not then how to find the interest of user?

Comment: Think of what you want to solve, (e.g. is it categorical or a continuous response, how will you deploy our model (e.g. in real-time of in batches), what other people have used (e.g. multinomial regression? collaborative filter?) and what is the resource you have (e.g. a 3yo laptop?a $30K in-house HPC? a smart-phone?) (And no reason for "*Sir*", I appreciate your politeness but it is somewhat excessive. :) )

Comment: OK I will again think about these things.